# How to repopulate fields in Zoo:Visitor registration form?

Tags: zoo-visitor, fields

I'm using inline error handling with a Zoo:Visitor registration form. When the form is submitted with an error, such as "The email you chose is not available", the fields do not repopulate with the values submitted. I have `value={field_name}` in place for each field. How should this work?

Thanks!

Mark

**UPDATE**

Here's some of the code. You'll see value for `member_firstname` is set. Yet when I submit the form and get it back with an inline error for `email`, nothing is displayed in the `member_firstname` field:

```
            {exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form
                error_handling="inline"
                return="members/success"
                include_jquery="no"
                allowed_groups="7"
                preserve_checkboxes="yes"
                }

                <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="" />

                <p><label for="email">Email*</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" />
                {error:email}
                <label for="member_academic_discount" class="checkbox"><input id="member_academic_discount" name="member_academic_discount" type="checkbox" /> I am a student or teacher registering with a .edu email address.</label></p>

                <p><label for="password">Password*</label> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" />
                {error:password}

                <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password*</label> <input id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" type="password" value="" />
                </p>

                <p><label for="member_firstname">First Name*</label> <input id="member_firstname" name="member_firstname" type="text" value="{if member_firstname}{member_firstname}{/if}" />
                {error:member_firstname}
```

Comment: Shouldn't value be empty for registration? http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/registration.html#registration-tag-examples

Comment: That's what I started with, and just reverted it to try that again. Still no values when the page reloads and errors are displayed.

Comment: Just checked a form of mine that's working, and I'm using conditionals like value="{if member_firstname}{member_firstname}{/if}". Do you also have error_handling="inline" parameter set?

Comment: Updated with some of my code. Still not seeing `member_firstname` populate when an error is displayed.

Comment: Commenting because I'm curious to see if there's a good solution for this; if you're getting the error message via a mechanism like Custom System Messages, I wonder if you couldn't direct the user back using the JavaScript method that lets you go back one page in the history, rather than reloading the registration form as a fresh page load?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Nick! But that's bad UX. Server-side validation shouldn't depend on browser history, and SafeCracker/Channel Form/Zoo Visitor should prefill those fields if it's displaying inline errors. The two go hand in hand. This should be supported functionality.